# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined when sending an EJS form to Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to nodeJS, the `req.body.email` and `req.body.password` in the file `signupRoutes.js` do not seem to be picking up the form data on the front end of my project.

Any idea why? The specific error is `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')"`.

signup.ejs:

```
<form action='/signup' method="post">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

signupRoutes.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const User = require('../models/userModel');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('./signup');
    res.end();
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }); 
    user.save();
    res.redirect('/index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

userModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  }, {timestamps: true})

  const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  module.exports = User;
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const homepageRoutes = require('./routes/homepageRoutes');
const signupRoutes = require('./routes/signupRoutes');
const loginRoutes = require('./routes/loginRoutes');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const dbusername= process.env.DB_USERNAME;
const dbpassword= process.env.DB_PASSWORD;
dbURI = `mongodb+srv://${dbusername}:${dbpassword}@testingcluster.ix9mpsg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
mongoose.connect(dbURI).then((result) => app.listen(4000)).catch((err) => 
console.log(err));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('assets'));

app.use("/index", homepageRoutes);
app.use("/signup", signupRoutes);
app.use("/login", loginRoutes);
```

Thanks for your time. Side note: I am aware you need to add more security to passwords, I'm just testing posting data into mongoDB for now.

Here's one thing I tried due to a user suggestion. It was to change `email: req.body.email`, on `signupRoutes.js` to `email: res.json({requestBody: req.body.email})` as well as adding `app.use(express.json());` above the routes in "server.js".

It just returned a blank page with an empty object, It also did not post the data into MongoDB.

Comment: I tried using "email: res.json({requestBody: req.body.email})" in signupRoutes.js and it just showed me a blank page with an empty object, it also did not post to the MongoDB. I also added "app.use(express.json());" in the server.js file, i added it just about the routes.

Answer (score -1):

In `server.js` after this line `app.use(express.static('assets'))` or just before the route handlers, add the below line to parse the coming request and attached it to `req.body`.

Without `req.body` is `undefined`, the reason why you are getting that error. Also `app.use(express.json())` doesn't   parse data coming from a `from`.

```
express.urlencoded({extended: false})
```